# Is it possible to set different "rem" for different Web Component with Angular 2's ViewEncapsulation.Native?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, web-component, bootstrap-4

I want to make component with ViewEncapsulation.Native which uses Bootstrap 4 where others use Bootstrap 3. Here's component with Bootstrap 4:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm }    from '@angular/common';

import { Hero }    from './hero';
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/bootstrap.css'], //Bootstrap 4 CSS file
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class HeroFormComponent {}
```

And in `index.html` Bootstrap 3 is loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The problem is that when Bootstrap 3 is included, it makes everything very small. You can see how it looks in my [Plunker: Angular 2 ViewEncapsulation.Native  with Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4](https://plnkr.co/edit/gCon3P75pO0hKqrXrLDm?p=preview). When Bootstrap 3 is commented, everything looks better. I suppose that problem happens because Bootstrap 4 uses `rem` to style buttons:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.25;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

With [Bootstrap 4](https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css), `rem`, as root em, is set to `16px` for `html` tag:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

But [Bootstrap 3.3.6](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) sets it to `10px`:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Because Bootstrap 4 styles are included in Shadow DOM, they are not applied to HTML (and that's good). But because of it my component's styles will use `10px` as `rem` instead of `16px`. I have tried to set styles for component itself and for first element in its view:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/bootstrap.css'],
  styles: ['hero-form, #parent-element {font-size: 16px;}'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class HeroFormComponent {}
```

But it didn't work. I think it should work in this way by default - if `rem` will be the same for every Shadow DOM it will make having multiple CSS frameworks in one project (and it could be craaazy useful, for example for migration from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4) very hard. Is it possible to set different `rem` for different Web Component, without changing Bootstrap files to do not use `rem`? Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use `ViewEncapsulation.Native`? For this to work you need to load polyfills for non-Chrome browsers. I'm pretty sure Boostrap won't work properly with native Shadow DOM enabled. Do you have any reference that states that Bootstrap can be used with Shadow DOM and how?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer With `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` I got the same result, there is no specific reason to use `ViewEncapsulation.Native` but this is a try (not a production code) - if it is a possibility to achieve my goal without `ViewEncapsulation.Native`, it would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way to change `rem` but you could leverage something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/bootstrap.css', 'app/my.css'],
```

**my.css**

```
.btn {font-size: 16px;}
.form-control { font-size: 14px;}
```

See also plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlEZ7230O6SzRjNRyRvN?p=preview